# RHEL 6.5 on VMWare workstation 11 - unable to connect via ssh

Tags: ssh

I have installed a RHEL 6.5 (NIRMAN) on vmware workstation 11 and added two ethernet cards

eth0 - has been bridged to direct physical network (192.168.1.71)
eth1 - NAT

eth0 is pinging well from my external local network ( 192.168.1.12) and vice versa is also happening. However I am unable to connect to NIRMAN via ssh from 192.168.1.12 as well as through putty from windows machine .

Configuration files are shared below

```
[root@nirman ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=d94588e0-baf4-487b-844b-d71f09d7ccd1
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=192.168.1.71
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
DNS1=4.2.2.1
IPV6INIT=no
USERCTL=no
HWADDR=00:0C:29:C1:BE:F5
MTU=1400
PREFIX=24
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
NAME="System eth0"
LAST_CONNECT=1429995602
[root@nirman ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
DEVICE=eth1
HWADDR=00:0c:29:c1:be:ff
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=d94588e0-baf4-487b-844b-d71f09d7ccd1
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
[root@nirman ~]#
```

```
[root@nirman ~]# cat /etc/networks
default 0.0.0.0
loopback 127.0.0.0
link-local 169.254.0.0
[root@nirman ~]#
```

route table shown below

```
[root@nirman ~]# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     192.168.1.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.184.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth1
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
[root@nirman ~]#
```

sshd daemon running status

```
[root@nirman ~]# ps -aux | grep -i sshd
Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.8/FAQ
root       2335  0.0  0.2 100364  4472 ?        Ss   02:37   0:00 sshd: root@pts/0
root       2501  0.1  0.2 100364  4496 ?        Ss   02:42   0:02 sshd: root@pts/1
root       4057  0.0  0.2 100364  4188 ?        Ss   02:46   0:00 sshd: root@notty
root      17745  0.0  0.0  66604  1208 ?        Ss   03:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
root      17748  0.0  0.0 103256   876 pts/1    S+   03:16   0:00 grep -i sshd
[root@nirman ~]#
```

I even disabled SELinux context and the iptables

```
[root@nirman ~]# cat /etc/selinux/config

# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
#SELINUX=enforcing
SELINUX=disabled
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these two values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted

[root@nirman ~]#
```

The below is the error message that I am gettign while trying to connect from 192.168.1.12 (falcon)

```
[root@falcon ~]# ssh -vv root@192.168.1.71
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.71 [192.168.1.71] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.1.71 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.71 port 22: Connection timed out
[root@falcon ~]#
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `iptables-save`? I think the connection is dropped by firewall.

Answer (score 0):

iptables-save result is as follows

```
[root@nirman ~]# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Sun Apr 26 17:51:11 2015
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [60:7625]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth+ -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 69 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9102 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9101 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9102 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9103 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Apr 26 17:51:11 2015
[root@nirman ~]#
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe iptables is blocking you.

Try to issue the following command:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

If, after that, SSH connections are permitted, you found your problem ;) To permanently solve it, follow these steps:

1. issue `yum install setuptools system-config-firewall system-config-firewall-tui`
2. run `setup`
3. select "firewall" and follow the wizard to open SSH service.